# MySQL return a single row only when all rows are the value of the WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a dataset like this:

```
col1    col2
John    1
John    1
Emily   1
Emily   2
```

A simple `select distinct col1 from table where col2 = 1` returns John and Emily.

I want a query that results in only John, because Emily has at least one other row where col2 does not equal 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY. In time, this could prove problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a having clause:

```
select col1 
from table 
group by col1 
having count(distinct col2) = 1
and min(col2) = 1
```

**Edit**

Salman's answer looks nice too:

```
select col1 
from table 
group by col1  1
having count(*) = count(case when col2 = 1 then 1 else null end)
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit further Benny?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique ID column, you can do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Col1
FROM
    table t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 <> t2.col2 AND t1.ID < t2.ID
WHERE
    t1.col2 = 1
    AND t2.col1 IS NULL
```

That query takes all rows from table and tries to find another row in the table with the same name, but with a higher value in col2.

An alternative is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    col1
FROM
    table
WHERE
    col2 = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT
                    NULL
               FROM
                    Table T2
               WHERE
                    Table.col1 = T2.col1
                    AND Table2.col2 <> T2.col2)
```

This query finds all rows in the table where there aren't any another rows with the same name but with different values in col2.

Answer (score 0):

i currently don't have a mySQL data engine, but this works on MS-SQL engine.
hope you could find some hint.

```
select name, avg(cast(num as decimal(4,2) )) from test1
group by name
having  avg(cast(num as decimal(4,2) ))=1
```